# Modifying tabular environment to longtable and adjust box

Tags: tables

I have the following tabular code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
Name & Formula\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
Parameter 1 & $\phi_{1}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc+bca+cab+a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3ab+2ba+3bc+\left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}}+dad+bdba+abc+a^{b}c^{b}d^{a}+a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+dab$\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

for sake of exposition. Here, I have a long list of parameter values, which would easily span a few pages in length. Moreover, it is also wide. One quick fix for me was to use the adjustbox package, which did seem to do the trick, but which squishes the text in width (making it impossible to read long parameter definitions as the text becomes too small). Is there anyway to combine the adjustbox with the longtable environment? A potential fix could be to add additional horizontal spacing for each definition such that it spans more than 1 line and is still legible. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `xltabular` package and creating an `xltabular` environment that can span multiple pages? As the code below shows, it's easy to create a variant of the `X` column type that (a) suspends full justification while performing automatic line breaking, (b) allows hanging indentation, and (c) processes the cell contents in inline math mode automatically. Oh, and an `xltabular`-based table can span multiple pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' env.
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em$}X<{$}}
\begin{document} 

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|L|}
\hline 
Name & \mbox{Formula} \\ 
\hline 
Parameter 1 & \phi_{1}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc+bca+cab+a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3ab+2ba+3bc+(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x})^{1/(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x})}+dad+bdba+abc+a^{b}c^{b}d^{a}+a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+dab \\
\hline 
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. However, I have not been able to reproduce it. One reason is because I have $\phi_{1}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc+bca+cab+a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3ab+2ba+3bc+\left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}}+dad+bdba+abc+a^{b}c^{b}d^{a}+a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+dab$\  , which are the $ signs in front of the symbols, as well as the \tabularnewline command. As I have generated this table on lyx, I am unable to change this except manually. Is there any way to incorporate this in the xltabular environment?

Comment: @KwameBrown - If you don't want to remove the `$` symbols, which serve to initiate and terminate inline-math mode, from the input stream, you should change `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em$}X<{$}}` to `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em}X}`. Can you spot the two differences? :-) While in inline math mode, I find the input of `(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x})^{1/(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x})}` to be easier to read than what's produced by `\left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}}`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico :). Very helpful. Although it works now, the one issue is that some formulas still are not recognized for line breaking purposes. For instance, a long embedded formula, such as one within fractions, underbraces or left+right outside braces does not break, and instead runs off the side of the page. If you have any suggestions regarding such circumstances, please let me know :)

Comment: @KwameBrown - Please post a new query with further, actual details about the expressions in question, and ask for advice on how they might be line-broken. I guess the only generic suggestion I have is to see if you can widen the text block or, equivalently, maket the margins narrower.

Answer (score 4):

For starting point just simple one page table. By use of the `tabularray` package you can get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c X[c, mode=math] },
             row{1} = {mode=text}
             }
Name        & Formula           \\
Parameter 1 & \phi_{1}=a^{2} + b^{2}+c^{2} + abc+bca+cab+a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} + 3ab + 2ba +3 bc + \left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}} + dad + bdba + abc + a^{b}c^{b}d^{a} + a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} +  dab   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Extend it to long table is simple, instead of `tblr` you should use `longtblr` (see MWE below), but you should be aware, that any kind of long table can be split only between pages only between rows:

**Edit:** Added promesed example of long table using `longtblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4in, 
            margin=1in]{geometry} % that can be seen split 
                                  % of table between pages
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {The Caption},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c X[c, mode=math] }, 
                  rowhead = 1,
%                  row{even} = {gray!30}, 
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, c},
                 }
Name        & Formula           \\
%
Parameter 1 & \phi_{1}=a^{2} + b^{2}+c^{2} + abc+bca+cab+a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} + 3ab + 2ba +3 bc + \left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}} + dad + bdba + abc + a^{b}c^{b}d^{a} + a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} +  dab   \\
%
Parameter 2 & \phi_{1}=a^{2} + b^{2}+c^{2} + abc+bca+cab+a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} + 3ab + 2ba +3 bc + \left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}} + dad + bdba + abc + a^{b}c^{b}d^{a} + a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} +  dab   \\
%
Parameter 5 & \phi_{1}=a^{2} + b^{2}+c^{2} + abc+bca+cab+a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} + 3ab + 2ba +3 bc + \left(a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^{x}+b^{x}+c^{x}}} + dad + bdba + abc + a^{b}c^{b}d^{a} + a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} +  dab   \\
    \end{longtblr}
\lipsum[1][5-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)